# Transacciones anidadas en sequelize no esta funcionando

Tags: nodejs, sequelize

No estaria pudiendo realizar un post anidado en mi base de datos.
En este caso tengo una relacion n:1 entre los modelos tab y section. Un tab puede tener multiples sections
Dejo a modo de ejempĺo lo que seria el cuerpo de mi request. En este caso es un tab con una section adentro.

```
    tab = {
     name: 'name',
     position: 0,
     process_id: 266,
     descriptor_f: 'NAME',
     section: [{
        name: 'New Sec',
        process_id: 266,
        position: 0,
     },
     {
        name: 'New Sec2',
        process_id: 266,
        position: 1,
     }
     ]
    }
```

En el cuerpo del request puede venir un arreglo de tabs (por eso el for) Estoy tratando de realizar el post anidado de estos dos modelos pero solo se me guarda en base de datos el tab y no la seccion.

```
    const formPost = async (req = request, res = response) => {
        try {
        const { form } = req.body;
        if (form.tabs.length > 0) {
            for (const tabb of form.tabs) {
            const tab = await Tab.create(
                {
                name: tabb.name,
                position: tabb.position,
                process_id: tabb.process_id,
                created_by: tabb.created_by,
                descriptor_f: tabb.descriptor_f,
                section,
                },
                {
                include: Section,
                }
            );
            console.log(tab);
            console.log(tabb);
            }
        }
        console.log(form, res);
        return null;
        } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        return err;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Hello, we are in Stack Overflow in Spanish please edit your question by translating it so it can be accepted and answered, also to prevent it from being closed ;)

Comment: Gracias @Israel-ICM , corregido.